# Adding another 3 days in my function date()

Tags: php

Code :

```php
<?php echo date('Y/m/d'); ?>
```

Echo :
2022/03/18

what i need is adding 3 days of the current day

any possible solution ?

Exemple :

the code will echo this :

2022/03/21

Comment: @Luckyfella Yes

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php echo Date('y:m:d', strtotime('+3 days')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date = date('Y/m/d');
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 3 days'));
```

Also there is a \Datetime class in PHP:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

You can for instance say:

```
+ 1 week
```

or

```
+ 2 days
```

or

```
- 3 years
```

The date() function gives the date string in specified format. So if on 31 december 2022 you say "+ 1 day" the date becomes 1 januari 2023.

If you then `echo date("Y", strtotime("31 december 2022 + 1 day"))` it will say "2023"

Comment: Thanks mate, also i got a question '+ 3 days' is php know that 'days' go to '/d' ? and 'years' go to '/y' etc.. ?

Comment: strtotime sort of makes sense of a lot of logic ways to specify a point in time. I will make an addition to the answer.